# Parse - enabling local datastore produces error

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to enable Parse's local datastore and I am setting it up how they suggest in the manual:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" clientKey:@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];

    ...
```

I am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: ''enableLocalDataStore' must be called before 'setApplicationId:clientKey:''
```

I have tried placing the `enableLocalDatastore` line below the `setApplicationId` line and I get the same error. I have not enabled `cachePolicy` either. What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Big old NEVERMIND here - I had already enabled the datastore and was trying to enable it again...didn't realize that when I setup parse initially I had already enabled it.